# Make nests cli swagger plugin work for external models

Tags: typescript, nestjs

So I would like to try putting to use this swagger plugin that comes with nestjs.

It works if I define some class, let's say `CreateUserDto` but I would like to use some types from a third party library, in my case it's `@adyen/api-library` and it has classes like `Notification`, `NotificationResponse` etc, I'd like to use them as my request/response dtos. Is it possible with this plugin?

I tried inheriting like:

```
export class AdyenNotificationDto extends Notification {}
```

and putting that in `adyen-notification.request.dto.ts`

But it didn't help.

And in case it's not possible, does it mean that I'd have to duplicate? That's, I would have to create a dto with all the props from, say, the `Notification` class and then keep them in sync from then onwards?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to compile the external package with the `nest build` command while using the swagger plugin. The reason being is that during the build, Nest reads the AST of the classes and adds the appropriate decorators before the `tsc` process gets kicked off. When you are just building the application that makes use of the already built package, there's no AST to read and decorate, so you don't get the ability to decorator an already compiled package

Comment: I see, I got it, thank you a lot for the explanation! But I'm not sure I understand how to compile the external package with this script while using the plugin...I tried using this `--builder` option on the build script. Did not work. Could you please elaborate slightly more on this?